# Python numpy array negative start index with colon notation

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an array like:

```
a = np.arange(0,10)
```

Why does `a[-1:9]` give an empty result?  I expected it to give a result containing a[-1], a[0], a[1], ... a[8].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slice is interpreted as starting at `a[-1]`, which is the same as `a[len(a)-1]`, so `a[-1:9]` is equivalent to `a[9:9]`, which is an empty list. Your expected result isn't a contiguous range, which is what a slice must produce.

Comment: I see. In my mind, it should expand the range first, so [-1,0,1,...,8], then alias the -1 to 9, resulting in [9,0,1,2,...,8].  All I was trying to do was recreate the np.roll() function using indexing.

Comment: `np.roll` code is complex because it can work on any axis.  But basically, for your shift it does `res[0]=a[-1]` and `res[1:] = a[:-1]`.  You can't do the roll with one slicing expression.  `slice` produces a `view`, and a `roll` cannot be a `view`.